# pass environment variable to firefox without using the shell

Tags: firefox, snap

I'm doing some ssl/tls debugging using firefox and wireshark. I have to pass the SSLKEYLOGFILE variable to firefox. My current solution is starting firefox with bash using:

`echo "SSLKEYLOGFILE=$SSLKEYLOGFILE; /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" | snap run --shell firefox`

Is there a way to modify the desktop launcher so that I can normally start firefox without using a shell workaround?